# Generic type to repository for couchbase using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm creating an utility in Spring Boot to connect and insert/upsert data into the couchbase in the more generic way possible.

I have something like this:

```
public interface GenericRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<MyClass, String> {
}
```

Where I have `MyClass` I would like to accept **any kind** of document to insert into couchbase.

I have tried some things like using the generic type T but without success because I got the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't
>   find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!

My structure is: service (interface/impl) > DAO (interface/impl) > repository

Extra info: Across the above model I am passing a Generic type T. I am calling the service with my Pojo with the `@Document` annotation.

The goal is to remove the "dependency" of having one repository class for each type of Document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have generic repositories (bit hacky) but with some limitation. Assume you have documents;

```
@Document
public class MyClass1 extends BaseClass {

    private String text1;

    public MyClass1() {
        super();
        setType(Type.MyClass1);
    }

    // getter/setters
}

@Document
public class MyClass2 extends BaseClass {

    private String text2;

    public MyClass2() {
        super();
        setType(Type.MyClass2);
    }

    // getter/setters
}
```

with `BaseClass`;

```
@Document
public class BaseClass { 

    private Type type;

    // other common fields if any, and getter/setters

    public enum Type {
        MyClass1, MyClass2
    }
}
```

Then you can have the following repository;

```
public interface GenericRepository<T extends BaseClass> extends CouchbaseRepository<T, String> {

    public List<T> findByType(BaseData.Type type);

    public default List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return findByType(clazz.newInstance().getType());
    }
}
```

and use it like;

```
@Autowired
private GenericRepository<MyClass1> mc1Repository;
@Autowired
private GenericRepository<MyClass2> mc2Repository;

public void doStuff() {
    MyClass1 myClass1 = new MyClass1();
    myClass1.setText1("text1");
    mc1Repository.save(myClass1);
    mc1Repository.findAll(MyClass1.class).forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.getText1()));

    MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2();
    myClass2.setText2("text2");
    mc2Repository.save(myClass2);
    mc2Repository.findAll(MyClass2.class).forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.getText2()));
}
```

will print out;

```
text1
text2
```

But be aware that the documents will be all in same collection that is the collection for the `BaseClass`

Also this won't work with more than one extension (like `MyClass1 extends Mid1`, and `Mid1 extends Base`)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: You can build a class that does generic manipulation of an entity (save/delete/update) via the CouchbaseOperations class. All you need to do is to inject it in your service or custom repository.

I don't think this is possible via the Spring SDK (Couchbase just implements the Spring's spec). However, you can create a single generic repository using reflection and the standard Java SDK:

```
    Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("localhost");
    cluster.authenticate("username", "password");
    Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("bucketname");

    // Create a JSON Document
    JsonObject arthur = JsonObject.create()
        .put("name", "Arthur")
        .put("email", "kingarthur@couchbase.com")
        .put("interests", JsonArray.from("Holy Grail", "African Swallows"));

    // Store the Document
    bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create("u:king_arthur", arthur));
```

Comment: Using Spring is one of my requirements. The API that will consume is a spring microservice. That code is the standard couchbase example for the SDK. I need a generic repository which will be able to handle with all the spring stuff (annotation), MVC pattern and so on.

Comment: You might be able to do this via some hack but this is not natively supported.